# Блокировка Edit'a при выборе поля в ComboBox'e

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

В combobox'e есть 4 итема

```
Прием сотрудника  
Увольнение сотрудника  
Отпуск  
Командировка
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе "Увольнение сотрудника", блокировалось поле Edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вешайте на `ComboBox` обработчик `OnChange`:

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit.Enabled := ComboBox.ItemIndex <> 1;
end;
```